# Incompatible types between SVGPathElement and <path> when using spread operator React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to make a styled Path in React that accepts the same props as a native svg path:

```
let Path = (props: SVGPathElement) => {
    return (
        <svg>
            <path {...props} d="" />
        </svg>
    )
}
```

I got the following errors from typescript:

```
The types of 'style.backfaceVisibility' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "hidden" | "visible" | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SVGPathElement` is type of `path` as element, like

```js
const path = document.createElement('path') as SVGPathElement;
```

it should be `React.SVGProps<SVGPathElement>`

```js
const Path = (props: React.SVGProps<SVGPathElement>) => {
  return (
    <svg>
      <path {...props} d="" />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

- `React.HTMLProps<T>` for html tags
- `React.SVGProps<T>` for svg tags